# Unable to delete phone numbers in Twilio REST API in PHP

Tags: php, twilio

Hi I keep geting the following error when I try to delete a number from my twilio subaccount using REST API in PHP

my code is;

```
$number = $twClient->account->incoming_phone_numbers->get($number_Sid);
$twClient->account->incoming_phone_numbers->delete($number->sid);
```

The error that I am getting is;

```
[22-Aug-2013 09:40:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception   'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The requested resource was not found' in   C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\twilio-twilio-php-  732e6f6\Services\Twilio.php:226
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\twilio-twilio-php- 732e6f6\Services\Twilio.php(145): Services_Twilio->_processResponse(Array)
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\twilio-twilio-php-732e6f6\Services\Twilio.php(179): Services_Twilio->_makeIdempotentRequest(Array, '/2010-04-01/Acc...', 1)
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\twilio-twilio-php-732e6f6\Services\Twilio\ListResource.php(71): Services_Twilio->deleteData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array)
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\testers\web2call\application\controllers\clientphonenos_controller.php(518): Services_Twilio_ListResource->delete('PN397fc000ce6f8...')
#4 [internal function]: ClientPhoneNos_controller->data_form('delete', '+14139926551_AC...')
#5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\system\core\Cod in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\twilio-twilio-php-732e6f6\Services\Twilio.php on line 226
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already successfully deleted the phone number, Twilio will return a 404 Not Found to you, which the PHP library will interpret as a RestException. You can only delete the phone number one time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override exception by using this syntax:

```
    try
{
 // do something that can go wrong
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
 throw new Exception( 'Something really gone wrong', 0, $e);
}
```

Here's another live sample for sending messages with an exception catcher:

```
<?PHP

require "Services/Twilio.php";

// Set our AccountSid and AuthToken from twilio.com/user/account
$AccountSid = "{ACCOUNTSID}";
$AuthToken = "{AUTHTOKEN}";

// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

/* Your Twilio Number or Outgoing Caller ID */
$from = '2126404004';

$people = array("212-716-1130"); 

$body = "Enter your text message here";

$errorIds = array(); //user ids array which had broken phones

foreach ($people as $to) { 
    try
    {
    $client->account->sms_messages->create($from, $to, $body);
    echo "Sent message to: $to \n <br>";

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {  //on error push userId in to error array
        $count++;
        array_push($errorIds, $to);
    }
}

print_r($errorIds);

?>
```

Without catching the exception, the script will die with an error like:

```
<br>PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The message From/To pair violates a blacklist rule.' in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/twilio/Services/Twilio.php:149
```